# subtract from column with the maximum values in sequential manner in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, sequence

I am still learning how to do loops and if-else statements in R. I can  do the process in long hand method but I am going to implement them in a large dataset so I need to process them in loops/if-else.

My data looks a little bit like the sample data frame below. One of the columns contain the column number of the maximum value within the row:

```
     x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   x6   x7 max_index max_val
1  56.1 56.8 99.4 44.6 50.4 74.9 17.7         3    99.4
2   9.1 46.1 74.2 64.3 62.3 68.8 85.7         7    85.7
3  83.3 84.5 18.4 93.2 17.6 69.7 23.4         4    93.2
4  94.0  9.7 46.8 25.0 96.9 69.2 94.8         5    96.9
5  21.5 64.1 89.1 87.7 59.7 88.0 73.5         3    89.1
6  53.0 94.9 87.2 19.6 55.9 48.5 82.9         2    94.9
7  52.2 79.1 20.6  9.9 18.3 21.5 92.5         7    92.5
8  42.5 33.0 36.9 45.0 43.9  7.6 45.3         7    45.3
9  89.3 20.6 41.7 74.8 67.4 21.0 49.1         1    89.3
10 21.2 92.6 86.3 76.3 68.6 44.8  8.8         2    92.6
```

What I want to do is subtract the 3 succeeding columns (from the maximum) from each other  like this:

```
j1 <- max.col(df[,1:7], "first")
df$max_index <- j1
df$max_val <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), j1)]

i1 <- j1 + 1
i2 <- i1 + 1
i3 <- i2 +1

value <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), j1)]
value1 <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), i1)]
value2 <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), i2)]
value3 <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), i3)]

df$max_val <- value
df$max.up1 <- value1
df$max.up2 <- value2
df$max.up3 <- value3

df_x1 <- df$max_val - df$max.up1
df_x2 <- df$max.up1 - df$max.up2
df_x3 <- df$max.up2 - df$max.up3
```

After doing that, I would like to know if all 3 outputs (df_x1, df_x2, df_x3) are all positive and add a column that says "TRUE" and "FALSE" if not.

I would like my final dataframe to look like this:

```
     x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   x6   x7 max_index max_val t.or.f
1  56.1 56.8 99.4 44.6 50.4 74.9 17.7         3    99.4   FALSE
2   9.1 46.1 74.2 64.3 62.3 68.8 85.7         7    85.7   NA
3  83.3 84.5 18.4 93.2 17.6 69.7 23.4         4    93.2   FALSE
4  94.0  9.7 46.8 25.0 96.9 69.2 94.8         5    96.9   NA
5  21.5 64.1 89.1 87.7 59.7 88.0 73.5         3    89.1   FALSE
6  53.0 94.9 87.2 19.6 55.9 48.5 82.9         2    94.9   FALSE
7  52.2 79.1 20.6  9.9 18.3 21.5 92.5         7    92.5   FALSE
8  42.5 33.0 36.9 45.0 43.9  7.6 45.3         7    45.3   FALSE
9  89.3 20.6 41.7 74.8 67.4 21.0 49.1         1    89.3   FALSE
10 21.2 92.6 86.3 76.3 68.6 44.8  8.8         2    92.6   TRUE
```

How will I simplify my code? Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, if the maximum value is in a higher column number, like `max_index` of 7 (`max_val` 85.7), what should be considered as the succeeding columns?

Comment: hi @Ben, max_index is the column number of the maximum value from x1 to x7 while max_val is the value itself. The succeeding columns are the next 3 columns to the right of max_index.

Comment: I understand the first sentence, but still confused. I don't see any columns to the right of x7 (and only 1 to right of x6, and 2 to the right of x5). What happens then?

Comment: @Ben sorry for the confusion, it should be:  j1 <- max.col(df[,1:7], "first"). anything with succeeding columns less than 3 from the max would be classified as "NA".

Comment: Can you explain how you have first values as `FALSE` and last value as `TRUE` ?

Comment: @RonakShah FALSE is if at least one result of subtracting the adjacent column is negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I here is `data.table` solution with structured data approach:

```
library(data.table)

dt.m <- read.table(text = "
x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   x6   x7 max_index max_val
1  56.1 56.8 99.4 44.6 50.4 74.9 17.7         3    99.4
2   9.1 46.1 74.2 64.3 62.3 68.8 85.7         7    85.7
3  83.3 84.5 18.4 93.2 17.6 69.7 23.4         4    93.2
4  94.0  9.7 46.8 25.0 96.9 69.2 94.8         5    96.9
5  21.5 64.1 89.1 87.7 59.7 88.0 73.5         3    89.1
6  53.0 94.9 87.2 19.6 55.9 48.5 82.9         2    94.9
7  52.2 79.1 20.6  9.9 18.3 21.5 92.5         7    92.5
8  42.5 33.0 36.9 45.0 43.9  7.6 45.3         7    45.3
9  89.3 20.6 41.7 74.8 67.4 21.0 49.1         1    89.3
10 21.2 92.6 86.3 76.3 68.6 44.8  8.8         2    92.6", header = TRUE)

dt.m <- data.table(dt.m)
dt.m[, row.id := 1:.N]

# melt data to make it easy to work with, excluding max.val and max.index
dt <- melt(data = dt.m, measure.vars = 1:7, id.vars = "row.id")

# replicate max.val and max.index which are already provided in example
dt[, max.val := max(value), by = row.id]
dt[, max.index := which(value == max.val), by = row.id]

dt[, x.index := 1:.N, by = row.id]

# filter to values after the max value
out <- dt[x.index >= max.index]
# keep max value and 3 values post max value 
out <- out[, post.max.index := 1:.N, by = row.id][post.max.index <= 4]
out <- out[order(row.id, x.index)]
out[, previous.x := shift(value)]
out[, change.x :=  previous.x - value]
out <- out[max.index != x.index]

# check if all values are positive
res <- out[, .(all.next.positive = all(change.x > 0)), by = row.id]
# add result to the original data
dt.m <- merge(dt.m, res, by = "row.id", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: hi @Bulat,  when I run this part: `dt <- melt(data = dt, measure.vars = 1:7, id.vars = "row.id")`  it give me this error: `id variables not found in data: row.id`

Comment: Can you try now

Comment: it worked! thanks! now I need to replicate the process in my real data with 46000 rows.

Comment: Should not be an issue for data.table